# Как настроить выбор ОС?

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, astra-linux

Я установил Astra Linux на отдельный жёсткий диск. То есть у меня два жёстких диска один с Windows 10 , другой с Astra Linux. Как мне настроить выбор ОС когда включаю компьютер? Сейчас грузиться всегда Windows 10. Даже если в boot menu выбираю диск на котором Astra Linux.

Comment: Установи Grub обнови его после этого он найдет и Windows и Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Выключи в Windows 10 "Быстрый запуск"

По пути:
Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления\Электропитание\Системные параметры